# Format string in an insertRule javascript statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking to change the :hover style of a nav element through Javascript using insertRule. The background color of the nav link will change based on bgndImgIndex. Is this possible with Javascript or am I just plain wrong?

```
var bgndImgIndex = 0;
var colorSelect = ['#ffa800', '#ba2a2a', '#5ad339'];

var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

sheet.insertRule("a:hover {background:{0} !important".format(colorSelect[bgndImgIndex]), 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally possible. It seems the issue was that `.format` does not exist on the String prototype in JS. I usually use ES6 template strings for this task in JS, please see the working example:

```js
var bgndImgIndex = 0;
var colorSelect = ['#ffa800', '#ba2a2a', '#5ad339'];

var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

sheet.insertRule(
  `a:hover {background:${colorSelect[bgndImgIndex]} !important`
);
```

```html
<a>Test</a>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Definitely coming on here anymore rather than stewing for hours waiting for divine inspiration. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! Didn't you see the error regarding the invalid call to `format` in your browser console though?

Comment: Yeah I did, I was just leaving it in there as an example of what I was trying to achieve. Also this is my first post so I was bound to do something wrong haha.